# Could protobuf read text file which has no schema but just data?

Tags: protocol-buffers

For example, the proto file is like this.

```
message {
  required int key = 1;
  repeated int value = 2;
}
```

The text file is like this where the first column indicates key while the others indicates the repeated value.

```
3391 [ 4847 3948 4849 ]
9483 [ 4938 48497 71 ]
...
```

Could protobuf read and parse this text file?

Comment: Protobuf *isn't text*... well, here's a json-esque version,but usually it isn't text. Is your actual data serializer by a protobuf library?

Comment: Protobuf can parse binary data serizalized by it and json-like file that has schema. My file is neither. It just has data but not schema. For example, repeated element could represented by "[ ... ]".

Comment: ah, so you are talking about the json-like format. This is the minority usage (binary is the norm), so worth making that explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, protobuf has no support for custom text formats.

You'll have to write custom parser code for it, which can then convert to protobuf or whatever other representation you might want.